# Request Time Out, Error much earlier than passing the maximum time out time

Tags: php, android, database, timeout, database-connection

My android app connects to the database, many times in many activities via PHP. in PHP, i Have this code to connect database

```
   class db_connect 
   {
       protected $db_conn;
       protected $db_name = "database";
       protected $db_user;
       protected $password;
       protected $db_host ="localhost";


       function __construct($username,$pass) {

           $this->db_user = $username;
           $this->password = $pass;

       }

       function connect(){
           $this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;        
           dbname=$this->db_name",$this->db_user,$this->password);
           $this->db_conn->exec("set names utf8");
           return $this->db_conn;
       }
       function disconnect()
       {
           $this->db_conn = null;
       }

       function __destruct() {
       }
}
```

So, when I need to connect the database from other class, I just do:

```
$dbconnect = new db_connect($user,$pass);
$connection = $dbconnect->connect();
```

then after executing, I do disconnection as
    $dbconnect->disconnect();

My Php5.ini has this: ( I dont wanna change it).

```
; Default timeout for socket based streams (seconds)
  default_socket_timeout = 60
```

But the problem is, when I try to connect in database, it replies with "request time out" message, just in 4/5 seconds. then If I try again another times, generally it gets connected.
Can anybody please suggest me, what am I doing wrong? Why is it sending request time out message in 5 seconds, even if I have 60 seconds of time out set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure right off what your issue is ( probably re-opening an unclosed connection ), however I would suggest using a singleton pattern for your connection class.

It goes something like this

```
final class PdoWrapper{

    protected static $_instance;    
    protected $_conn;
    protected $db_name = "database";
    protected $db_user = "user";
    protected $password = "pass";
    protected $db_host ="localhost";

    private funciton __construct(){
        $this->_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name",$this->db_user,$this->password);
        $this->_conn->exec("set names utf8");
    }

    private function __clone(){}

    public static getInstance(){
        if( !self::$_instance ){
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function getConnection(){
        return $this->_conn;
    }
}
```

And you would use it like this

```
 $conn = PdoWrapper::getInstance()->getConnection();
```

The deal is that this will maintain your connection so you always use the same one simply by calling the `getInstance` method.  Things to note are that the class is final and the `constructor` and `clone` functions are private to prevent duplication of this class and the database connection.

As a further note you do not have to disconnect from the database as PHP will do this automatically when the script ends.  As a general rule it takes time to connect to the database so in the long run you are better keeping one single connection open then closing and opening one or opening multiple connections.

**In replay** to having the connection class accept input for the connection parameters.

While this at first seams a very reasonable thing and easily accomplished, that is somewhat of a naive view. To explain this the complication arises because once you allow input into the class you violate the nature of the "Singleton" pattern, which is a single instance with a unified point of access, basically an immutable class instance ( cannot be changed after initialization ).  Preventing mutation is why the class is marked as final ( cannot be extended ) and has both a private `__construct` and `__clone` method.

The best way to explain this is to say you are giving a preference to when the singleton is created, by passing in connection details.  So you will always have to create it with the same connection details or make the initial connection first before you can use it.  To further complicate this you open it up to passing in different connection details, and with that there will be no clear way to know what set of credentials were used at any given time or what connection it holds. You also will have an issue of deciding if the class ( connection ) was initiated with this data or if it need to be re-connected using the new connection details.

Fortunately, we can solve all these issues by creating what I call a Multi-Singleton, which is a bit of an oxymoron in itself.  Anyway, for this you will want 2 files, one for the connection information  ( a configuration file ) as you don't really want your database connection details sprinkled all throughout your application.  Just think of the day when you want to update your database password and have to search all your code for copies of it.

So we will start with that file ( dbconf.php )

```
<?php
$conf = array();

$conf['database1'] = array(
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'user' => 'user1',
    'pass' => 'pass1'
);

$conf['database2'] = array(
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'user' => 'user2',
    'pass' => 'pass2'
);
```

In this file we have a multidimensional array with the top level key matched to the name of the database, and the other data being connection details for that database.

Then we make a few minor changes to the above class. ( this hasn't been tested, but should show the general idea )

```
<?php
final class PdoWrapper{

    protected static $_instances = array(); 
    protected static $_dbconf;
    protected $_conn;

    private funciton __construct( $database ){
        if( !self::$_dbconf ){
            require 'dbconf.php';
            self::$_dbconf = $conf;
        }

        if( !isset( self::$_dbconf[$database] ) ){
            die( 'Unknown database in '.__FILE__.' on '.__LINE__ );
        }

        $this->_conn = new PDO(
            "mysql:host=" . self::_dbconf[$database]['host'] . ";dbname=$database",
            self::_dbconf[$database]['user'],
            self::_dbconf[$database]['pass']
        );
        $this->_conn->exec("set names utf8");
    }

    private function __clone(){}

    public static getInstance( $database ){
        if( !self::$_instance[$database] ){
            self::$_instance[$database] = new self($database);
        }
        return self::$_instance[$database];
    }

    public function getConnection(){
        return $this->_conn;
    }
}
```

The things changed here were the import of the config file, and a way to tell the class what database instance to use.  Now with these changes you call the class like this.

```
 $Conn1 = PdoWrapper::getInstance( 'database1' )->getConnection();
 $Conn2 = PdoWrapper::getInstance( 'database2' )->getConnection();
```

So as you can see now you can have multiple Singletons, each one holds exactly one connection to one database. With this method there is no preference set to the first call to the class.  No initial connection that needs to be made. Also, you are not needlessly duplicating your database connection details all over the place.

One last modification I would make is to add a shortcut function like this

```
public static function getInstanceConnection( $database ){
    $I = self::getInstance( $database );
    return $I->getConnection();
}
```

While this is not necessary it allows you to make one call and reads a bit better from outside the class. So to duplicate the initialization code above you would do this after adding that method in.

```
 $Conn1 = PdoWrapper::getInstanceConnection( 'database1' );
 $Conn2 = PdoWrapper::getInstanceConnection( 'database2' );
```

The reason behind not just returning the connection from the `getInstance` method ( besides clarity of naming ) is you may want to add some other functionality to the class latter, in which case you would need access the Singleton instance itself. A simple example of this off the top of my head would be to add a method to see if a table exists like this.

```
public function tableExists( $table ){
    $stmt = $this->_conn->prepare('SHOW TABLES LIKE :table');
    $stmt->execute( array( ':table' => $table ) );
    return $stmt->rowCount() ? true : false;
}
```

Then you would need to get the instance to call it.

```
$I = PdoWrapper::getInstance( 'database1' );
$I->tableExists( 'table' );
//or with method chaining you can do this.
PdoWrapper::getInstance( 'database1' )->tableExists( 'table' );
```

You never know what functionality you might want to add latter so always keep those options open.

Essentially this is a Singleton pattern merged with a Factory pattern.  For more detailed information on programing patterns see this wiki article

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix, Appreciated. I will apply and see it.

Comment: This is the basic method I use, but I slimmed down the class, so I haven't tested this exact code but it should be pretty close. In my full code I use a separate PHP config file and have instance as an array of instances so I can connect to multiple databases.

Comment: @AtristicPhoenix, got more confused on implementation. How would you pass the users data and database name in this case ?

Comment: @Shasi - I would do that by modifying the class to accept that as input, that said you wonder into an area that gets a bit murky, I will explain in my answer.

Comment: Happily accepted answer. I have seen many people discouraging to use singleton. But I think, its the best (and not too time consuming) way for implementing the only-single instantiation.